# Why is this question unanswered?

Tags: support

It appears that there is a question under the [laser](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/laser) tag that is also under the  unanswered tab. This question does, however, have an answer. Is this a bug, or intentional?

Answer (score 3):

"Unanswered" really translates to "No Upvoted or Accepted Answers". The post you're asking about has one answer, but nobody has upvoted it.

Comment: I see, so mundane questions asked by unresponsive users may still be in the unanswered queue to this day? interesting.. edit: now that I check, some of my questions are in there... better fix that

Comment: This is in fact a bit of a bug in the SO system.  Questions that aren't in quite enough literal violation of anything to close, asked by hit-and-run posters which yield answers that are on the level of what the question deserves which is to say too poor to merit upvotes, can get stuck in the eternal churn loop.  It's an even worse problem on the Arduino site than here.